# How to add values for each entry in multivalued lists [ACCESS]

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to build up a database for chemical samples in ms-access.
For each sample I created a Combo box which allows multiple values where I can check all chemicals that I included in my precursor (the list is based on another table where I can add new chemicals).

Now I also want to save the mass of the chemical that I added to the sample and store it in the database. How do I add now for each entry in the multivalued list another value field in which I can add the mass?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand the question... You open the table in design view and add a new field? Or if it is used rarely, put it in a separate table. How much do you know about database design and normalization?

Comment: You need a third table with proper relationships. Do not use multi-valued fields. It will only come back to bite you later on. As mentioned by vicap, learn about database design and normalization.

Comment: I know nothing about normalization, but I'm eager to learn.
So you suggest that I create a third table where I link the sample ID to the chemical ID and add a value that says how much of what chamical I added to the sample?
eg.:

sample 1 / chemical 1 / 5g;

sample 1 / chemical 2 / 10g;

sample 2 / chemical 1 / 7g;

...

Comment: Yes, you just solved your question. :) You have a many-to-many relationship, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity . The mass is a 3rd column (besides Sample_ID and Chemical_ID) in the junction table.